# Html menu jumping to div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a menu containing links that targets an `iframe`. At the same time the web address is revealed in a separate `div`.

The code below works pretty well, but I discovered that the page jumps to the top of the web address text. I've tried a few strategies to to fix this (including placing a fixed position on a wrapper), but just can't seem to be able to stop the page from jumping to the address text.

Here is a snippet.

```js
<script>
  var Lst;

function changecolor(obj) {
  if (Lst) Lst.style.color = "#663399";
  obj.style.color = "red";
  Lst = obj;
}

$("a").click(function() {
  $("iframe").attr("src", $($(this).attr("href")).find("a").attr("href"));
}); 
</script>
```

```css
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.menu {
  font-size: 13px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 8px;
}
.header {
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 260px;
}
.hyperlinks {
  top: 50px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 50px;
}
#tabs p {
  display: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#tabs p.tab1:target {
  display: block;
}
#tabs p.tab2:target {
  display: block;
}
#tabs p.tab3:target {
  display: block;
}
iframe {
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">

  <div class="header">
    Title of site
    <br>
    <a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a>
  </div>

  <div class="hyperlinks">

    <p id='tab1' class='tab1'>
      <a href="https://www.wikipedia.org">"https://www.wikipedia.org"</a>
    </p>

    <p id='tab2' class='tab2'>
      <a href="http://dictionary.reference.com">"http://dictionary.reference.com"</a>
    </p>

    <p id='tab3' class='tab3'>
      <a href="http://www.thesaurus.com">"http://www.thesaurus.com"</a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#tab1" class="nav-tab tab1" onclick="changecolor(this)">
 Menu item 1<br><br></a>

    <a href="#tab2" class="nav-tab nav-tab-active tab2" onclick="changecolor(this)">
 Menu item 2<br><br></a>

    <a href="#tab3" class="nav-tab nav-tab-active tab3" onclick="changecolor(this)">
 Menu item 3<br><br></a>

  </div>

  <br/>
  <iframe>

  </iframe>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anchor makes it jump to the div having that id, for example when you click on `a` element having `href="#tab1"` it jumps to `div` element having `id="tab1"`

i wrote you a better version of your code:

```js
(function() {
 $('.menu a.nav-tab').on('click', function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  
  $('iframe').attr('src', href);
  $('.current-url').empty().append( $('<a>').attr('href', href).append('"'+ href +'"') );
  
  $('.menu a.nav-tab').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
  return false;
 });
})();
```

```css
a:active { text-decoration: underline; }

.menu {
 font-size: 13px;
 top: 100px;
 width: 260px;
 height: 100px;
 left: 8px;
}

.header {
 font-size: 13px;
 height: 50px;
 width: 260px;
}

.hyperlinks {
 top: 50px;
 width: 260px;
 height: 50px;
}

iframe {
 width: 260px;
 height: 260px;
}

.menu a.nav-tab { color: #663399; }
.menu a.nav-tab.current {color: red;}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id="tabs">
  <div class="header">
   Title of site <br> <a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a>
  </div>

  <div class="hyperlinks">
   <p class="current-url"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
   <a class="nav-tab tab1" href="https://www.wikipedia.org" >Menu item 1</a> <br />
   <a class="nav-tab nav-tab-active tab2" href="http://dictionary.reference.com"> Menu item 2</a> <br />
   <a class="nav-tab nav-tab-active tab3" href="http://www.thesaurus.com"> Menu item 3</a> <br />
  </div>

  <iframe></iframe>
 </div>
```

Comment: Both solutions work really well. The cleaned up code version is really amazing. It makes the coding much simpler by removing the CSS and the doubling up of hyperlinks in the HTML. makes a lot of sense to show the hyperlink through the button link itself rather than showing/hiding it with separate text. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Event.preventDefault();` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

```
$("a").click(function( evt ) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  $("iframe").attr("src", $($(this).attr("href")).find("a").attr("href"));
});
```

You're using HASH `#` fragments inside your anchors `href="#tab1"` and the browser will *follow* to that segment searching for the relevant `:target` ID element (the `id="tab1"` element). Here `preventDefault` prevents the default browser goTo/follow behavior.